# Can libpng15 be installed alongside libpng16 without any issues?

Tags: libpng

I am quite new to linux and have recently installed Ubunutu 18.04 LTS.

I am trying to install NASA GMAT (available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/gmat/). After downloading .tar.gz I extracted the archive and found a README file. The command line version of GMAT found in /bin of the file works perfectly fine.

However, when I try to run "./GMAT_Beta" I get the following error:

./GMAT_Beta./GMAT_Beta: error while loading shared libraries: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Now I have checked via Synaptics Package Manger and using apt command that I have libpng16-16 - installed version "1.6.34-1ubuntu.18.04.2".

I want to install libpng15 for GMAT to function. Can someone please guide me:
1. Where and how to install libpng15 from?
2. Will I have to remove the already installed version or can they co-exist together?

Comment: As you can see from the file list : `$ dpkg -L libpng16-16` (or https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/amd64/libpng16-16/filelist ) all file names are unique for libpng16-16. "libpng15" : No Ubuntu packages. Suggest, install from source https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng15/ .... **Note** : The two versions can be installed at the same time. No issues.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng15/ → 1.5.30 → → libpng-1.5.30.tar.xz

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem on compiling GMAT in my Linux PC. Here is the solution which worked for me on my Ubuntu 20.05.

1. Download, compile and install `libpng15.s0.15` from https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng15/older-releases/1.5.15/
2. In case if you end up with

   ```
   libjpeg: file not found
   ```

   try installing using the package manager:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libjpeg62
   ```